# Comparing two lists to find the common elements then sorting into three different list using python

Tags: python, excel, list, sorting, comparison

I am new to learning to code especially in python. But my task is to take a two lists like in excel and find the common elements of the two lists. Then in a separate spreadsheet, list the common element in one column call this list (same), list what is left in the 1st list call this column (onlycol1) and list what is left in the 2nd list call this column (onlycol2).

My example lists are:

```
col1                  

 1. apple           
 2. banana 
 3. pear
 4. kiwi

col2

 1. apple 
 2. orange 
 3. grapes
```

List should be sorted like this

```
same

 1. apple

onlycol1

 1. banana
 2. pear
 3. kiwi

onlycol2

 1. orange 
 2. grapes



col1= [apple, banana, pear, kiwi]
col2= [apple, orange, grapes]

set(col1) & set(col2)
```

Comment: Sorry, you need to have tried something yourself first.  If you have a specific question about a specific problem then please feel free to ask that, but this is not a homework writing service.  You'll thank us for that one day.

Comment: It'd be lovely if you posted your thought process and or attempt first so we could help you figure out what's wrong!

Comment: Thanks I am new to this I have my concept of how to sort it is just creating the 2nd part of the project but I will be glad to share what I have so far

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is by using the in-built Sets of python. In order to get the common elements, you can use the intersection. While to get the results that only exists in one column, you perform the Minus operation, just like we learn in Sets in Math.

```
col1 = ['apple','banana','pear','kiwi']
col2 = ['apple','orange','grapes']

common = list(set(col1)& set(col2))

onlyCol1 = list(set(col1) - set(common))
onlyCol2 = list(set(col2) - set(common))
```

Comment: Thank you this has been helpful so far I will continue to play around with It and I will definitely ask again if I have any questions